# IE getting [object Object] with turn.js

Tags: javascript, turn.js

I recently started using turn.js. However, I wanted to know how to make link so that a certain text would open up a page.

I found that -

```html
 <a href="javascript:$('#flipbook').turn('page',8)">test</a>
```

would work. But only chrome? Does anyone know why I would get [object Object] on IE? I am very new to Javascript.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that string?

Comment: _“Does anyone know why I would get [object Object] on IE?”_ - because of that terrible, old-school syntax you are using to add JavaScript functionality to a link. IE thinks whatever that method call returns, was supposed to be the “new content” it was supposed to display after that link was clicked.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help... It seems I just needed to add in ;void(0); into the line.

Answer (score -1):

So turns out the issue I had that I needed to add ;void(0); to the line and now it works!

Comment: That's a hack. Don't use javascript: urls for this. Use proper event listeners.

Comment: Can I ask why? If it still does the same job? Sorry I am very new and just want an understanding...

Comment: The purpose of a link is to navigate to a somewhere. You're generating the somewhere with JavaScript, and then destroying it with `void()`. So you've got a feature which has all the accessibility data saying "This is a link" and then making it not be a link. Instead, you can use a button (which doesn't announce itself to be a link) and `addEventListener` to make it do something with JS.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you for your response :)